# fact table should have measures from 'weak entity' or only parent entity's fields should be entered

Tags: ssas, entity-relationship, data-warehouse, olap, dimensional-modeling

i am new to dimension modeling and OLAP. 
I am trying to create a dimension model for a shop.

"order" table is having columns:

```
'order_id(auto generated), total_order_cost, date, product_Set_Id'.
```

"Product_set" table (contains products ordered in each order i.e. multiple rows for each order, tables logically linked by 'product_set_id' column) has columns:

```
'product_set_id, product_name, quantity,Cost_per_quantity'.
```

In the ER model "product_set" table is kind of weak entity dependent on "order" table.

My doubt is in the fact table 
case 1: i should add only `'order_id(fk)'` and `'total_order_cost(as measure)'`
==>in this case measures from "product_set" won't be there in fact table.

or case 2:i should add `'order_id(fk)','product_set_id(fk)' and 'cost_per_quantity(measure), quantity(measure), total_order_cost(measure)'` 
==>in this case there will be multiple rows for same `'order_id' and 'total_order_cost'`

There are other some tables like "customer" etc but i have doubt in above mentioned.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one suggestion always made is to create a surrogate key on the tables. My fact sales is such that it has the surrogate key which allows me to have the orderline data there and each orderline identified by a surrogate key (which I don't really use - but its not an issue) . That way you can follow case 2.

Does that answer the question?

Comment: First thanks for your answer. So, according to you i should remove 'total_order_cost' and keep 'order_id' in the fact table?? Is it fine that 'order_id' is repeating since there can be multiple products in an order??

Comment: hi in my design that is the case, i ve combined the order and orderline table in one FactSales table. That is why a aurrogate key is used. And no keep the total_order_cost (its a measure). But because order cost will remain the same, i would suggest if you can seperate it per order line. define your total_order_cost as cost_per_quantity * quantity

Comment: Thanks again now correct me if i am wrong, I understood your design. Your approach is good as it makes more sense but it is like an alternate solution. It is kind of 'star schema'. Still suppose we don't combine them in one table i.e. kind of 'snowflake schema' and go with two different tables. or let me reframe the problem as, **how we should enter measures and FKs in case of snowflake schema.**

Comment: You should always push for a star schema, yes there are other types of dimensions like, Mini Dims (Customer_Mini_Dim which would store customer data but will have its foreign table key in the fact table) or Outrigger (Customer_Demographics causing a snowflake as it has its foreign key in the Custmer Dim), and there are only a handful of scenarios where you could consider snowflaking but its best to have star schema to be able to get quick results. This is how kimball teaches us to do data warehousing.

Comment: In case for snowflake it can be complicated, but you'd end up with Order (PK- OrderID) and Orderline (PK- OrderlineID and OrderID - composite PK that is). And have orderID as the referencing key in both tables. But fact to fact relationships, I wouldn't do, adventure works has done it so I guess you can get away with it

Comment: Thanks for helping and being patient. I got your point that we should always push for 'star schema'. So, finally we can either go like you said i.e. by combining 'order' and 'orderline' and then using surrogate key. Another way i think is having only 'orderline' dimension(without 'order') and using 'order id' as degenerate dimension in 'FactSales'.

Comment: Orderline cannot be a dimension by its nature. It is one that contains measures. And you can either use 'orderID' as a degenerate dimension or  have 2 fact tables Order and Orderline (if you dont want to combine them). I used the work FactSales, when you combine the 2 (orderline and order- like i have). Is that clearer?